# How to clear filter on Telerik ASP.NET MVC Grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

I have a grid that allows the user to filter.  If the user changes the search word that is used to populate the grid, the filter from the previous search remains in place.

```
<label for="UserName"> 
    User Name:</label> 
<%= Html.TextBox("UserName", "") %> 
&nbsp; &nbsp; 
<input id="btnSearch" type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</p> 
<div class="<%= "t-" + Html.GetCurrentTheme() %>" style="width: 400px;"> 
<%= Html.Telerik().Grid<ADGroup>()       
        .Name("Groups") 
        .Columns(columns=> 
        { 
            columns.Add(c => c.GroupName).Width(350); 
        }) 
        .Sortable() 
        .Filterable() 
        .Pageable(paging => 
            paging.PageSize(20) 
        ) 
        .Ajax(ajax => ajax.Action("_GetGroups", "GroupSearch", new { userName = "John Doh" })) 
        .BindTo((IEnumerable<ADGroup>)ViewData["Groups"]) 
%> 
</div>
```

I have triggered the rebind of the gird to occur when btnSearch is pressed.

```
<% 
Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar() 
    .OnDocumentReady(() =>  
    { 
    %> 
    var groupsGrid = $('#Groups').data('tGrid'); 
    $('#btnSearch') 
        .live("click", function() { 
            var user = $('#UserName').val(); 
            // rebind the related grid 
            groupsGrid.rebind({ 
                userName: user 
            }); 
        }); 
    <%  
});
```

%>

I know that I can add the following code which will bring up the filter menu, but I'd prefer to be able to automagically clear the filter before or after the .rebind() call occurs.

```
$('.t-grid-filter:first') 
     .trigger('click');
```

Comment: just trying to understand what you are asking: you want to clear the filter and then rebind the grid when you click search?

Comment: Correct...  I basically want the filter that has been applied to be cleared anytime that I click the btnSearch button, ec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [korchev's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141158/how-to-clear-filter-on-telerik-asp-net-mvc-grid/2147111#2147111) inspiration...  I came up with the following that is executed before the rebind occurs.  It clears out the filter values and then applies the new (non-existent) values.

```
//Clear UI Filter Text
$('#Groups .t-clear-button').click();
$('#Groups .t-filter-button').click();

// rebind the related grid
groupsGrid.rebind({
    userName: user
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check my reply [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/automatically-clear-filter-on-mvc-grid.aspx).

Comment: The code does indeed clear out the text box filter value, but it doesn't actually change the behind the scene filter.  I think I'll have to also simulate the click on the actual filter button for this to work.  Please let me know when the official fix might be ready!